# Akka: Network overhead for watching actors

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

For sending messages from a sender (actor `Y`) to a `shard-entity` (actor `X`) we have two options:

1. Always send messages to `X` via the `shard-region` .
2. 1) Send a message via the `shard-region` once; 2) After getting reply from `X`, store its actor-ref in `Y`; 3) Watching `X` in `Y`; 4) Now `Y` can send messages to `X` directly.

In my opinion the second approach is better, but watching actors in a cluster environment could have network-overhead that should be considered.

So my questions:

1. How watching actors works internally (Is it pushed-based or pull-based or ...)?
2. So, should we worry about network-overhead for watching actors in akka?

Comment: You would usually use method 1. The reason is that sharded entities can and will be rebalanced to other nodes. The ShardRegion contains lots of functionality to make sure that during such events messages will be buffered and rerouted properly. It sounds like you might want to reimplement that functionality on top of watches? That might be possible but it's not really recommended.

Comment: Regarding cluster/remote watching, that should be fairly efficient. There's a `RemoteWatcher` in each ActorSystem which acts as a middle-man for watches to a remote actor. In addition, to the regular passive watch (register an entry in the watched actor), it also uses additional logic to find out a target ActorSystem might have gone away. For simple remoting (without a cluster) that involves heartbeating, i.e. some fixed amount of network traffic between two ActorSystem. For cluster, no extra heartbeating is needed because cluster state can be used to determine the state of a remote node.

Comment: Thanks @jrudolph. When second approach should be preferred?

Comment: I think the second approach has minimum (network/internal) overhead: It only involves one actor (`X`). while the first approach involves at least 3 actors (`shard-region`, `shard`, `X`). So i think when actor `Y` can handle some functionalities (e.g. retry on errors, retry on timeouts, ...) it's better to use the second approach. Is it correct?